# metapost making use of hyperref to other page /2nd question

Tags: hyperref, metapost

I think my previous posting is a mess with uncleaned format. So I'm posting revised one.

I am using lualatex 2020 and can make use of "\label{A:aaa}"
and "\ref{A:aaa}" to make reference between pages.

Now I am trying to use it between metapost page and normal page.
The result of my experiment so far is :
normal page -> mepost page    works but
metapost page -> normal page  is not working

I did two experiments.
One without minipage
label(btex { reference to the other page \ref{A:bb} } etex, origin) ;

One with minipage
label(btex
\begin{minipage}[t]{20em}
reference to the oter page \ref{A:bb}
\end{minipage}
etex, origin);

I would appreciate for any direction on this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document} 
\newpage
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\tableofcontents
\newpage 
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Normal Page}
This is \verb|\ref{A:metapostpage}| --->>> \ref{A:metapostpage}   
<<<---- click will change page to metapost page. 
\vskip 5cm 
This is \verb|\label{A:normalpage}| \label{A:normalpage} 
\newpage
\section{Metapost Page}
\begin{mplibcode}
    label(btex ~ etex, origin) ; 
    label.rt(btex 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{20em}
        This is \symbol{92}label\symbol{123}A:metapostpage\symbol{125} \label{A:metapostpage}  
    \end{minipage}
    etex, (50,-30)) ; 
    draw (0,0)--(250,0)--(250,-50)--(0,-50)--cycle ;
    label.rt(btex 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{40em}
    This is \symbol{92}ref\symbol{123}A:normalpage\symbol{125} -->> \ref{A:normalpage} <<--- click to change page to normal page. 
    \end{minipage}
    etex, (50,-170)) ; 
    draw (0,-150)--(450,-150)--(450,-200)--(0,-200)--cycle ; 
endfig ; 
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it would have been clearer to edit the original. But as is can you delete the original if it is the same question?

Comment: the previous posting delete is done. thanks.